# Что сделать с ошибкой ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND в браузере

Tags: html, html5

Я хочу запустить сайт, который сделал на HTML, но получаю ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND в браузере, и это со всеми сайтами которые я делал. Ошибка появилась вчера, раньше её не было. Помогите, пожалуйста её исправить. Вот код:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
   <h1>Это страничка с котиком</h1>
   <img src='cat.jpg' align='right' alt='Это картинка с милым котиком' width='600' height='450'>
   <img src='newImg/cat2.jpg' align='left' alt='Это картинка с милым котиком'>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Речь идёт о каком-то локальном веб-сервере или хостинге? Вы только что перенесли на него ваши сайты, а до той поры они лежали просто в папках на жёстком диске открывались *нормально* оттуда? Почему вы задаёте вопрос так, что другие вынуждены задавать много наводящих вопросов, прежде. чем смогут дать хоть какой-то ответ на ваш вопрос?

Comment: Я написал код, может это поможет?

Comment: Из приведённого вами кода видно, что вы подгружаете на страничке две картинки: cat.jpg, которая должна находится в одной папке с самим html файлом и cat2.jpg, которая должна быть в папке newImg. Есть ли в одной папке с вашим html-файлом такие папки и картинки?

Comment: Да, все картинки находятся в нужных папках. Проблемы возникают абсолютно со всеми моими проектами

Comment: Полный текст ошибки - в студию.

Comment: Вот что пишет браузер: Файл не найден. Возможно, он был перемещен или удален.
ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Comment: Часто в тексте такой ошибки есть продолжение, например, так: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND file:///D:/css/app.css
У вас ничего подобного нет? На какой именно файл браузер ругается?

Comment: Кажется нашёл из-за чего ошибка, в поисковой строке, не знаю почему, не полностью указывается путь к файлу. Не знаете как это исправить?

Comment: Как выглядит этот путь в браузере и где на диске лежит ваша страница? Пока мы занимаемся гаданием на кофейной гуще.